# HTML/CSS Flowchart not fitting in screen view

Tags: html, css, formatting, html-lists, flowchart

I'm trying to make a HTML/CSS flowchart. I want everything to fit into one screen view width-wise, but it's not at the moment. I don't mind individual boxes having a smaller width and the text inside the boxes wrapping.

I was hoping someone would be able to have a look at the CSS code - it seems like there should be a quick fix!

I got the original code from there:
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree

```
    <html>
<head>

<style>



li {
 white-space: nowrap; // stop the wrapping in the first place
 }

/*Now the CSS*/
 * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

 .greenBox {
border: 2px solid #007f00 !important;
background-color:#e5ffe5;
}

.redBox {
border: 2px solid #FF0000 !important;
background-color:#ffe5e5;
}


.tree ul {
padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
float: left; text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
content: '';
position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
right: auto; left: 50%;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
content: '';
position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 5px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #666;
font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
display: inline-block;

border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;

transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
border-color:  #94a0b4;
}

/*Thats all. I hope you enjoyed it.
Thanks :)*/
</style>


</head>

<body>
<!--
We will create a family tree using just CSS(3)
The markup will be simple nested lists
-->
<div class="tree" style="white-space: nowrap;">
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#">E. coli</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Live</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Keep</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                            <a href="#">Excreted</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="greenBox">Effective waste treatment</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Poor waste treatment</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                            <a href="#" class="redBox">Unknown consequence to environment</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Contaminate other people</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Stay in gut</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="redBox">Work too well -> copper deficiency risk</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Imbalance (overgrowth)</a>
                                        <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="redBox">Progressive recovery of the microbiome</a>
                                    </li>
                                            <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="redBox">Unpredictable damage</a>
                                    </li>
                                            <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="redBox">Digestive disorder</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Equilibrium with other flora</a>
                                        <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="redBox">Share genetic information - unknown danger</a>
                                        <ul>

                                </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="redBox">Mutation - unknown danger</a>
                                        <ul>

                                </ul>
                                    </li>
                                            <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="redBox">Integration into microbiome - danger</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="greenBox">Lose plasmid</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Dead</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                         <a href="#">After low absorption</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="greenBox">No consequence</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="greenBox">Modification of the gut microbiome</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                         <a href="#">After high absorption</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Modify Cu level significantly</a>
                                <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="greenBox">No consequence</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Modification of the gut microbiome</a>

                                <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="greenBox">Proliferation of neutral strains</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="greenBox">Proliferation of pathogenic strains</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="greenBox">Very low Cu absorption by gut</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

since your using float for .tree li .the list elements comes to the next line when it occupies the .tree entire width .so give a width to you parent container

Check this fiddle: I have updated ur code

Comment: Jsfiddle.net/ygpyn20f

Comment: Dear subbu1191, thanks very much, this has solved the problem of it being broken up. Another problem now is that I need to scroll width-wise to see the whole thing. I was wondering if there is a way for the box widths to be narrower automatically so that the whole thing fits onto one page, with the text wrapping onto multiple lines? Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much, this has solved the problem of it being broken up. Another problem now is that I need to scroll width-wise to see the whole thing. I was wondering if there is a way for the box widths to be narrower automatically so that the whole thing fits onto one page, with the text wrapping onto multiple lines?

Many, many thanks!
Gaurav